# Delete duplicate columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have table which has 4 columns and thousands of records. I want to delete a rows which are duplicate based on three column(say col1,col2,col3).
I have to delete row based on criteria like

```
1) found a row which has col1 and col2 equal and
2) in those duplicate record i have to delete those rows on which col3 is null- keep  one row
  (if no other record with combination of col1 and col2 doesn't have not null col3) 

col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
1    1    null
1    1    null
1    2    null
1    2    1
1    2    1
1    2    null
1    2    2
1    2    3
```

In this example i want to delete either 1 or 2. 3,4,5,6 has duplicate columns in and some of them has third column is not null and i want to keep only one row which has third column not null(if third column also equal keep only  one row)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have data which looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
1    1    null
1    1    null
1    2    null
1    2    1
1    2    2
1    2    3
1    2    null
```

Is it ok to delete the first 2 rows, since `col1` and `col2` match, and `col3` is null on both? If not, here's my sql:

```
DELETE FROM table_name A
WHERE  exists (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_name B
  WHERE A.col1 = B.col1
  AND   A.col2 = B.col2
  AND   B.col3 is not null)
AND A.col3 is null
```

Comment: it is deleting first two row which has null. but i want to delete only one row(if no other third column is not null)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_name A WHERE ROWID > (SELECT min(rowid) FROM table_name B
WHERE A.clmn1 = B.clmn1 AND A.clmn2 = B.clmn2 AND A.clmn3 is NULL AND b.clmn3 is NULL);
```

Check this ..
Comment if there is any error.

Comment: This does neither even pass the syntax check on Oracle nor does querying "> rowid" make any sense.

Comment: Clearly && was meant to be `AND`, and the comparison to ROWID means to simply pick one of the set of records with matching columns.